# How to reach HTML DOM via JQuery

Tags: jquery

Bit new to JQuery and i don't know how to reach this:

I need to change DOM via JQuery from this:

```
<li id="1_1_4" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee">1.1.4</li>
```

to this:

```
<li id="1_1_4" class="ui-widget-content ui-selectee ui-selected">1.1.4<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check"
                style="float: right; margin: 2px 7px 0 0;"></span></li>
```

**Edit:**
Also, if i want to revert it back, meaning there is a `<Span>` and i want to remove it. how can i do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Append

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#1_1_4').append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-check" style="float: right; margin: 2px 7px 0 0;"></span>');
});
```

### Remove

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#1_1_4 .ui-icon-check').remove();
});
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#1_1_4 span').remove();
});
```

Comment: Thank you. and i i want to remove the span? how can i do it?

Comment: can i remove only span tag? what happens if i have other elements besides the span?

Answer (score 1):

You might use the .append() function of jQuery:

```
$('.ui-widget-content .ui-selectee .ui-selected').append("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check' style='float: right; margin: 2px 7px 0 0;'></span>");
```

Or:

```
$('#1_1_4').append("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-check' style='float: right; margin: 2px 7px 0 0;'></span>");
```

Ref.  http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 0):

See here http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-replacement/

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    $( "#1_1_4" ).append( "<span class=\"ui-icon ui-icon-check\" style=\"float: right; margin: 2px 7px 0 0;\"></span>" );
```